# Vertical Section and Chapter Name in Margin

Tags: sectioning, titles, book-design, thumb-index

Sorry for the vague title, I honestly have no idea what they're called, so it makes googling for them rather hard. (**Edit** It's apparently called a "thumb index")

I'm looking to do something similar to this:
[image: picture of titles in margins]
Where the chapter and section headings that normally occur at the top of the page when using the *book* `documentclass` are instead flipped vertically and shoved into the margins as shown in the example picture above.

The colour of the box isn't exactly important and can be tweaked later on, but I do want a box around all three of these regardless.

So, can anybody help me out in figuring this out?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have much experience with latex code. I read discussions, manuals and here in this forum there are excellent discussions.
I'll list the solutions that I have found and that seem to me to be similar to your question. You will need to study the code and adapt it to your needs.. Once done ask a question in the forum with your code to solve the problems you don't know how to deal with.
I do this and they help me immediately. It takes a little patience with latex.

Similar discussion:

[Coloured swatch per chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224292/coloured-swatch-per-chapter)

[Chapter Title in rotated vertical box at the margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48641/chapter-title-in-rotated-vertical-box-at-the-margin)

[Rotated, running text in right margin?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54808/rotated-running-text-in-right-margin)

[How can I get the thumb index correct?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256046/how-can-i-get-the-thumb-index-correct)

[Automatically Center Text in Chapter Thumb Box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262560/automatically-center-text-in-chapter-thumb-box)

Comment: This really isn't an answer, you could have posted it as a comment perhaps.

Comment: In fact, I'm new here. Now I've  understand and so I have done in others. Thanks for the comment